# can't start Jenkins on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

I am trying to start Jenkins on Ubuntu Linux
When I write in my address line http://localhost:8080 chrome writes that "website cant be reach"

I followed this instruction in documentation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-16-04

output of command     `sudo systemctl status jenkins` is :

```
jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active:active (exited) since Thu 2017-04-20 16:51:13 UTC; 2min 7s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

than I ran this command `sudo ufw allow 8080`, the output is :

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

it seems that everything is okay. what the problem can be?

Comment: Are you opening Chrome on your Ubuntu system or another host?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue as well, and it was because the Java JRE was not installed. I had to install that, and then I was able to follow the Jenkins setup guide.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I had installed the JDK.  I always thought the JRE was included with the JDK, but just in case, I installed the JRE separately with "apt install default-jre".  Message was "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 59 not upgraded".  Indeed, still getting same "This site can't be reached" error.